# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$Id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I was trying to pass a parameter from my database to my view.

**Controller**

```
class StatisticsController extends Controller
{
    public function statistic()
    {
        $data = DB::table('statisticforteacher');
        
        return view('/statistics', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/statistics', 'StatisticsController@statistic');
```

**Blade/View**

```
<table class="table-responsive" 
       style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 15px;">
    <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Kapitel</th>
    <th>Frage</th>
    <th>Anzahl der richtige Antwort</th>
    <th>Anzahl der falsche Antwort</th>
    <th>Richtige Rate</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($data as $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$value -> Id}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> FrageBezeichnung}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> Kapitel}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> richtigeAntwort}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> falscheAntwort}}</td>
        <td>{{$value -> richtigeRate}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And from PHPMyAdmin, we can see a table named `statisticforteacher`, and each column name is also right.

[image]

However, I still get the following error.

> ErrorException Undefined property:
> Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data =DB::table('statisticforteacher');
```

Here `$data` return `query builder` instance so you have to return collection  in order to loop data so you have to use

```
 $data =DB::table('statisticforteacher')->get();
```

or

```
 $data =DB::table('statisticforteacher')->all();
```

if you have addition query condition then you have use `get()` not `all()` method

Comment: yes, right, how can I make such a stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

$data =DB::table('statisticforteacher')->get();